# Trying to set width of bootstrap progress bar using variable from constructor function in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm really new with React and having trouble with something. I'm trying to set the a progress bar's progress equal to a variable I have inside of a constructor function in my react component. I'm just using a regular old bootstrap progress bar. The progress bar appears, but no width setting I've tried will actually fill the progress bar. If anyone can help out I'd be grateful. Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SalesData from '../data/salesData';

class ProgressBar extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.ordersInProgress = 0;
        this.totalSales = 0;
        this.orderGoal = 260;

        SalesData.forEach(item => {
            this.ordersInProgress += item.orders;
            this.totalSales += item.orders * item.price;
        });

        this.progressBarPercentage = Math.floor((this.ordersInProgress / this.orderGoal) * 100);
        this.completedOrders = this.orderGoal - this.ordersInProgress;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="progressBarBlock">
                <div className = "progress progressBar">
                    <div className='progress-bar progressBarColor'
                         role='progressbar'
                         aria-valuenow='70'
                         aria-valuemin='0'
                         aria-valuemax='100'
                         styles={{width: this.progressBarPercentage}}>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default ProgressBar
```

tldr: I'm trying to set the progress bar progress equal to that progressBarPercentage I've calculated in my constructor function, and it's not filling. Again, thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: are you familiar with the concept of `state` in react?

Comment: oh wait.. i re-read your question. it's `style` not `styles`

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommemded to you class fields (e.g. this.ordersGoal) to keep data in, especially if your component depends on that data for rendering, as it will not track changes. this.state / this.setState() are designed fro this purpose.

2) It should be style, not styles, as already mentioned above

```
class ProgressBar extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    let ordersInProgress = 0;
    let totalSales = 0;
    let orderGoal = 260;

    SalesData.forEach(item => {
      ordersInProgress += item.orders;
      totalSales += item.orders * item.price;
    });

    const progressBarPercentage = Math.floor((ordersInProgress / orderGoal) * 100);
    const completedOrders = orderGoal - ordersInProgress;

    this.state = { progressBarPercentage, completedOrders };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="progressBarBlock">
        <div className = "progress progressBar">
          <div className='progress-bar progressBarColor'
               role='progressbar'
               aria-valuenow='70'
               aria-valuemin='0'
               aria-valuemax='100'
               style={{width: this.state.progressBarPercentage}}>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default ProgressBar
```

3) After a closer study I found numerous problems: 1) data should come as props 2) state is not needed in this case 3) component becomes stateless functional 4) the percentage was always zero due to an error in calculation

This is the sandbox to see it working https://codesandbox.io/s/o51lnz7o99

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, but this isn't working either. The this. needs to be removed from the const's in your code snippet, but either way I'm getting the same result. I'm trying to stringify the variable and add a % as well, and that does not work either. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Hi! Yes you are right about this. You could simply add `console.log(this.state);` as the first line of render() function and check in the console if data is correct. If it is (should be) then a different approach to work with bootstrap will be needed

Comment: also the salesdata should in principly come as props.. I'll update the exmaple now